# How to read "Date" value from "Excel" and send that value into "Date picker" using "Selenium WebDriver"

Tags: java, excel, date, selenium-webdriver

I used an excel sheet with `"Date"` as the cell type, in format `dd-mm-yyyy`

In selenium code i used below code

```
String value = String.valueOf(sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getDateCellValue())
driver.findElement(By.id("Datepickerid")).sendkeys(value)
```

But the date value is not entered into the date picker only `"--"` value is entered in the "Date picker" field. can any one help me how to read date value from excel and enter that date value into the "Date picker" field using `"Sendkeys"` method

Comment: Can you put this date picker code ?

Comment: which date picker code?

Comment: This date picker, where you're trying to put the date. I mean source code of the picker, or - if it's public - link to url where we could see how this date picker looks like.

Comment: <input name="ctl00$SingleMainContent$txtRegDate" type="text" maxlength="10" id="SingleMainContent_txtRegDate" tabindex="29" class="clxtxtwatermarkextendersmalltext" autocomplete="off" onchange="return calc3(this.value)" ontextchanged="return calc3(this.value)">

Comment: Is this "Date picker" is writable? I mean can you type something there using sendKeys command?

Comment: Using sendKeys not able to enter any data but manually i can able to enter date value

Comment: Are you sure that String value is valid for date picker ? Maybe it's in format, which is not supported by this picker ? What if you try to put literal date to picker ? For example: driver.findElement(By.id("SingleMainContent_txtRegDate")).sendkeys("2019-16-08") - or any other date in valid format.

Comment: The string format the date picker allows is "dd-mm-yyyy"

Comment: By using this code driver.findElement(By.id("SingleMainContent_txtRegDate")).sendkeys("11-05-2019"),  "--" is displaying in "Date Picker" instead of displaying "Date" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me to enter date value into the date picker text box. The solution is i commented the "Clear" statement . After that it is working . In spreadsheet also the cell has data like this '11-05-2019 ( starting with single quote)
WebElement date_Of_Reg = driver.findElement(By.id("SingleMainContent_txtRegDate"));
//date_Of_Reg.clear();  date_Of_Reg.sendKeys(data_entry_sheet.getRow(loop_Var).getCell(15).getStringCellValue());